# Obtener una palabra que no contenga ningún caracter alfanumérico ni antes ni después de esta

Tags: javascript, regex

Intento obtener una palabra, con la condición de que no haya ningún caracter alfanumérico ni antes ni después de esta, es decir una expresión así

```js
"num" // Match
"1 * num" // Match, solo a "num"
" num " // Match
"ISnumber" // Incluye "num", pero hay mas caracteres, no hay match
```

Intenté usar la siguiente expresión regular, pero no obtengo éxito

```js
function checkWordMatch(/****/) {
  return [...arguments].map(e => e.match(/^(?!.*[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}).*num.*(?!.*[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,})$/));
}

console.log(
  checkWordMatch(
    "num", // null
    "1 * num", // null
    " num ", // null
    "ISnumber" // null
  )
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si quieres que algo no este precedido por otra cosa tienes que usar Negative Lookbehind `(?<!...)`

```js
function checkWordMatch() {
  return [...arguments].map(e => e.match(/(?<![a-z0-9])num(?![a-z0-9])/gm));
}

console.log(
  checkWordMatch(
    "num",
    "1 * num",
    " num ",
    "ISnumber"
  )
);
```

La expresión `[a-z0-9]` no va a capturar la ñ o la á, para capturar todos los caracteres unicode quizá sea conveniente algo como `/(?<![\p{L}0-9])num(?![\p{L}0-9])/gmu` con el flag `u`

Answer (score 1):

Se usa **`\b`**, **límite de palabra**,
que coincide en una *posición* antes/después de `\w` (un caracter de palabra = `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`) cuando no hay un caracter de palabra del otro lado (`\W`, inicio o fin de string).

Regex que coincide con `"num"` como palabra completa:

```
/\bnum\b/
```

---

> Aserciones en MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Assertions